# I have some questions about HQL syntax

Tags: hibernate, hql

guys. I'm a novice learning Hibernate.Recently,I learned some konwledge about Hibernate query language. When learned FROM systnx,I want to konw '**SELECT A FROM A**' is same with '**FROM A**'?

I ask for GTP,it can't give me a correct answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the rather antiquated Hibernate query language [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from) we can see that either version is acceptable:

```
FROM A
SELECT A FROM A
```

You would use the `SELECT` version more typically if you wanted to choose certain fields from the entity, e.g.

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM EntityA
```